# How to fix an error with undefined error with cancan and devise in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

I am trying to create permissions in my Rails app with Devise and Cancan.

ability.rb:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        if user.role ==  'admin'
            can :manage, :all
        else
            can :read, :all
        end
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role
  # attr_accessible :title, :body


  def role(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end

end
```

view

```
            <% if can? :update, review %>
                <p><p><i><a href = '/products/<%= @product.id %>/reviews/<%= review.id %>/edit'>Edit</a>
            <% end %>
```

I get an error saying undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass for this line in the view.  Any advice on how to fix this?
I've been trying to use https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization as a guide

Comment: is the user currently signed in? since you do not have `@user = user || User.new` or similar in you initialize block anywhere that a `can?` method is used when the user is not logged in will fail. since it is alerting you that role can not be called on a nil class I would think there is no `current_user` object to call it on.

Comment: Another note, I would recommend renaming the `role` method since you already have an attribute with the same name this could be causing unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
```

to see if that fixes your role error.

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    def initialize(user)
        if user.role ==  'admin'
            can :manage, :all
        else
            can :read, :all
        end
    end
end
```

that way you can rule out user being nil.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) by the creator of the cancan gem. It explains what you are trying to do in depth a little better than the link you are following.